# On ajax load script is not load and slider is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

When the page is load first time the slider is working fine but when I change the value in the slider, on change event of slider there is an AJAX call and on success result I have replace some div content with result.

But that slider is not displaying after success result on that AJAX call.

I have put an alert in that slider function, same thing happens, on page load all alert are working fine but after ajax call they also not work.

See code below:

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider(
{
    range: true,
    min:min,
    max:max,
    values: [ selectedMinValue,selectedMaxValue ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) 
    {
        //Note: Currency Custom formatting is not supported.
        $( ".currentMinPrice" ).html( '@(Model.Context.CurrencySymbol) ' + ui.values[ 0 ]);
        $( ".currentMaxPrice" ).html( '@(Model.Context.CurrencySymbol) ' + ui.values[ 1 ]);
    },
    change:function(event,ui)
    {
        alert("hello2");
        var url=removeParameter('@(currentURL)',"price");
        var newUrl=url.replace(/&amp/g,'');
        if(isAjaxRequest)
        {
            callAjax(UpdateQueryString("price", ui.values[0] + "-" + ui.values[1],newUrl));
        }                    
    }
});
```

AJAX function:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (result) 
    {   
        // Result is in html
        $('#div').replaceWith(result);
        $('#ajax-loading').hide();
        DisplayFilter();

        //Lazy Loading
        $("img.lazy").show().lazyload(
        {
            effect: "fadeIn"
        });
        $(window).trigger("scroll");
    }
});
```

I use a jQuery 1.10.2, this code is already working in jQuery 1.7.2 version.

Why it's not working in 1.10.2 version of jQuery?

Please give suggestion

Thank you all
regards,

Comment: Learn to use your browser's developer tools and put a breakpoint in the AJAX function.

Comment: IS the slider inside of #Div?

Comment: @bsayegh: #div is a Different div on same page , on ajax success result we replace ontent of that Div with ajax result,on 1st load of page slider is work but when i slide it and on slider change event it's work but slider is not disply after that ajax result.

Comment: @LeeTaylor :- we have already check Browser's developer tools and put a break point in ajax function but there is no any error found. and note that this code is working fine with jquery version 1.7.2 but now we use jquery version 1.10.2 and this code is not working with thsi jquery 1.10.2. why? can you advice